# Chrome renders strange chord shapes in D3 Chord Diagram

Tags: google-chrome, d3.js, chord-diagram

I noticed after an update to latest version of Chrome (Version 44.0.2403.157 (64-bit)), the Chrome browser starts to wrongly render triangle-like shapes for chords on the Chord Diagram which do not look correct. Please take a look at [this example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/) and [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/eleyine/raw/6846156/).

This was not an issue with previous Chrome versions (e.g. Version 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit)). Also Firefox or Safari do not have this issue at all. All chords are drawn perfectly as smooth curves.

What is causing the bug in Chrome and is there any fix that we can implement?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this issue is no longer reproducible in Chrome Canary. So we can assume the future version of Chrome has resolved the bug.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same !